# Multiple Instances of Angular Generic Service

Tags: angular, generics, service

I have a generic service GenericService:

```
export class GenericService<T> {
      // API URL has to be overrided
      apiUrl = `${environment.apiUrl}/endpoint`;

      private _dataState$ = new BehaviorSubject<DataState>(DEFAULT_STATE);
      get dataState() { return this._dataState$.value; }
    
      protected http: HttpClient;
      
      constructor(http: HttpClient) { this.http = http; }

      .
      .
      .
      .
      .

}
```

It is extended by multiple services:

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CurrenciesService extends GenericService<Currency> {
    apiUrl = `${environment.apiUrl}currencies`;
    constructor(http: HttpClient) { super(http); }
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PositionsService extends GenericService<Position> {
  apiUrl = `${environment.apiUrl}positions`;
  constructor(http: HttpClient) { super(http); }
}
```

In my components (e.g PositionsComponent) I have the following code

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-positions',
  templateUrl: './positions.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./positions.component.scss']
})
export class PositionsComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  dataState: DataState;
  constructor(
    public positionsService: PositionsService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dataState = this.positionsService.dataState;
  }

@Component({
  selector: 'app-currencies',
  templateUrl: './currencies.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./currencies.component.scss']
})
export class CurrenciesComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  dataState: DataState;
  constructor(
    public currenciesService: CurrenciesService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dataState = this.currenciesService.dataState;
  }
```

DataState object contains information about paging, sorting, etc.

The problem is that this datastate object is similar for both components. Services are not unique and share this datastate object, which is not the behavior I want.

Can you help me identify the problem?

Comment: If a component needs a separate instance of the service then you can provide it on component level @Component({
  selector: 'app-currencies',
  templateUrl: './currencies.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./currencies.component.scss'],providers:[CurrenciesService]
})

Comment: Should i leave providedIn 'root' on currencies service or is it not necessary?

Comment: If you want all the component to have different instance then you can remove the providein property